# can't take any element from JSONObject in java

Tags: java, android, json

i have problem with taking element from JSONObject.

this is my code :

```
public static void getJSON(){
    String googlemap = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=29.0+35.0&sensor=true";

    HttpResponse httpRespone = GET.sendGetReq(googlemap);
    try {
        //Get Stream and convert it to String
        String inputStreamAsString = convertStreamToString(httpRespone.getEntity().getContent());

        //convert from String to JSONObject
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(inputStreamAsString);
        String formatted_address = json.getJSONObject("results").getString("formatted_address");


    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when i called to

```
String formatted_address = json.getJSONObject("results").getString("formatted_address");
```

i get JSONException...

my json is here :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=29.0+35.0&sensor=true
[json link](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=29.0%2035.0&sensor=true)

and i want to take the value of "formatted_address".
can you please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`results` is a `JSONArray`

`{}` this is a `JSONObject`

`[]` this is a `JSONArray`, that can contain X `JSONObjects`, wich you can access either by a `for` loop, or with the index (if you know it)

```
String formatted_address  = json.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("your json")
String formateed_address = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results").
                           getJSONObject(0).getString("formatted_address");
```